# repaint the panel repeatedly after click a button

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am trying to write a program that has 2 buttons which whenever i press the first, the square should repaint over and over and changed it's color while pressing the second one.
but it just repaint one time :(
if anyone can help i'll appreciate it.

```
class Squre {
JFrame frame;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
MyPanel panel;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Squre s= new Squre ();
    s.go();

}
public void go(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel= new MyPanel();
    button1= new JButton();
    button2= new JButton();

    button1.setText("START");
    //button1.setSize(30, 20);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(700,700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER ,panel);// add panel
    frame .getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, button1);// add the west button
    frame .getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, button2);//ADD THE EAST BUTTON
    button1.addActionListener(new StrListener());
    button2.setText("EXPLOSION");
    button2.addActionListener(new ExpListener());
}
private class StrListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        do{
            frame.repaint();

        }
        while(e.equals(button2)==true);
}
}
private class ExpListener implements ActionListener{
  //  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}class MyPanel extends JPanel{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

     int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);  
     int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);   
     int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255); 
     Color rn=new Color(red, green, blue);
     g.setColor(rn);
     g.fillRect(250, 250, 50, 50);



}
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e.equals(button1) // event not equal to a button
```

`e.equals(button1)` never become true because a `event` not equal to a `button`.but `repaint` runs one time because it's a do while loop.

you should use

```
e.getSource().equals(button1);
```

to check if clicked button is `button1` or not.

but even you use `e.getSource().equals(button1)` you will not see color changing as you expected .if you run this time consuming while loop inside [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) , you will block the `EDT` thread .hence colors not get changed but if you put a `sout` you will see that loop is running continually .you can use  [swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for this. swing timer will not block the EDT.

using Swing timer....

you should import `swing timer` //`import javax.swing.Timer;`

```
private class StrListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(button1)) {
            Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]